# Getting unexpected error while writing test for smart contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript, unittesting

Hey guys I am writing tests for a NFT Markeplace smart contract, I have two contracts one for Marketplace and one for a basic ERC721 NFT. So while I am writing test I have a listNFT function in the Marketplace contract, now the problem is that the List Nft function checks for approval of token that is the token is approved for listing or not, while calling the function I am already calling the `_approve()` function from the ERC721 openzeppelin, but still the test fails and says that The NFT is not approved for listing, can anyone help me solving the problem?

Code- https://github.com/DeadmanAbir/NFT-Marketplace

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why have you created another function for approving, it is already there, and secondly please console.log the return of it so that we can check the tx has success. I will help you further more

// Edited

Well i found it [code link where the error is](https://github.com/DeadmanAbir/NFT-Marketplace/blob/3feeecd30087915d57352eec80ede9fa63403c57/contracts/market.sol#L48) well you are checking to approve the NFT contract instead of Market COntract address.

Comment: Hey i am getting a object while console.log the approve function but the error is still same

Comment: Please use the `approve(address to, uint256 tokenId)` function actually

Comment: Hey I have used it like ```tx=await basicNft.connect(deployer).approve(instance.address, TOKEN_ID);``` and console.log(tx) gives a object with many parameters but still the prolem remain unsolved, can you just run the code locally to understand the problem.

Comment: can you send me what it returns

Comment: hey I can't because the comment section doesn't allow sending pictures and uploading long codes....you have to run it locally to see it.

Comment: ok let me try, i get to you in a few

Comment: Thanx for helping just try if you can figure it out

Comment: look i updated the answer, it was a small issue

Comment: Hey got this, thanx mate thanx a lot